# Template method runs however Visual Studio 2015 shows error

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2015

I have a template method GetComponent

```
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity();
    ~Entity();

    void AddComponent(Component* c);

    template <typename T>
    T* Entity::GetComponent()
    {
        return (T*)components.at(0);
    }
};
```

In the main.cpp

```
auto e = new Entity();
e->AddComponent(new Transform());
// later ...
auto t = e->GetComponent<Transform>();
```

This runs fine, however Visual Studio 2015 is showing error:
class "Entity" has no member "GetComponent"

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetComponent()` is defined inside the class, try stripping the `Entity::`

```
T* GetComponent() ...
```

Comment: Indeed, its a copy paste error since I moved the code from cpp file to the header.